# How to border white and box-shadow this text

Tags: html, css

I want to edit text like this image and how to write it ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods to achieve this. The most common is to use `text-shadow`, which can be used to set multiple text shadows. This doesn't look great though (see fiddle below).

Other options include using the `-webkit-text-stroke-width` property, though ***this is a prefixed property which might be dropped in the future***, so beware (again, see fiddle below); however, this method is the simplest, and closer-matching than the `box-shadow` method in terms of aesthetics (especially at larger sizes).

The final option (probably the most consistent with the desired aesthetic, whilst still retaining good cross-browser compatibility) is to use an SVG (as above, see fiddle below).

In the SVG example, I have also added text over the initial text to cover the fact that strokes encroach within the text (i.e. adding a stroke of 4px to text will add 2px outside of the text, and 2px within, causing the text to become less 'bold'). You can do the save effect on the second example (which also uses strokes) by using (for example) a pseudo-element (i.e. `<h1 data-stroke="PIN">PIN</h1>`).

The drawback here is obviously there is a bigger chunk of nested HTML.

What method you pick will depend entirely on the context you are using this for. And as asked above, without any code to see, a better answer cannot be given without you elaborating more and providing an example of what you have done so far.

```css
body {
  background: #eee
}

h1 {
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: red;
}

/* Well-supported, but looks a bit naff */
.shadow {
  text-shadow:
      -2px 0 0 #fff,
      0 -2px 0 #fff,
      2px 0 0 #fff,
      0 2px 0 #fff,
      2px -2px 0 #fff,
      -2px 2px 0 #fff,
      -2px -2px 0 #fff,
      2px 2px 0 #fff,
      3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

/* Uses prefixes, which might be dropped in the future */
.stroke {
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Using text shadow -->
  <h1 class="shadow">PIN</h1>
  
  <!-- Using webkit stroke -->
  <h1 class="stroke">PIN</h1>
  
  <!-- Using svgs -->
  <svg width="100px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 100 60">
    <defs>
      <style>
        text {
          font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
          font-size: 50px;
          fill: red;
          alignment-baseline: middle;
        }
        .outline {
          fill: white;
          stroke: white;
          stroke-width: 4;
         }
      </style>
      
      <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2 2" result="shadow"/>
        <feOffset dx="3" dy="3"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <text x="10" y="30" style="filter: url(#shadow); fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)">PIN</text>
    <text x="10" y="30" class="outline">PIN</text>
    <text x="10" y="30">PIN</text>
  </svg>
</body>
```